# Couldn't Import a dart file in a new dart file (Target of URI doesn't exist)

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub, flutter-packages

My flutter project has a separate dart file for each functionality, So, I tried to import a dart file in a new dart file to access the functionality in that file, but I got this error "Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:filename.dart'. Try creating the file referenced by the URI, or Try using a URI for a file that does exist"
I tried solutions like restarting the Ide, flutter clean command and pub get, Most of the solutions for the same error have to deal with packages, it can be solved by adding package name in dependencies. But this is a dart file, how do I solve it.

Answer (score 0):

When using the import function and going to the root folder with 'package:*', you need to first write the flutter project folder name, and then after that the file or subfolders.
All this but skipping the 'lib' folder.

As an example:

```
import 'package:flutterProject/subFolderInLib/filename.dart'
```

Hope this was understandable and worked! :)

Comment: I tried this already but I still get that error.

Comment: Could I please get you to check what the file is encoded with?
You can do this by opening the dart file with the notepad and pressing 'save as', and then besides the save button there should be an option to change the encoding, there you can see what the current encoding is.

Answer (score 0):

Write the filename in snake_case, make sure it starts with a lower case letter. Solved it for me.